# implode a data from database to echo checkbox as checked

Tags: php, implode

I have a data array which is separated  by a comma in database.

[image]
now, what i want to do is implode the strings from the column **purpose**.

[image]

and make that checkbox lists in my form `echo checked;` if the list is in the database.

*hope you guys can help me out*. Thank You!

Comment: Please stop storing CSVs in columns. This is not how they are meant to be used. 1 value per column.

Comment: Please, show us, what have you tried to solve the problem. Otherwise we won't help.

Comment: Your database design is bad. You need to create a child table for storing purpose fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: okay i will edit it and post my code.

Comment: @user3783243 that is not the solution of my problem.

Comment: If corrected your problem will be much easier.

Comment: @user4035 you're right! my database design was bad. i can't convert it to different array string number because it's just store in one field. I will just figure it out how to do it with that kind of database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example (Not the proper way to design your code though)  .

```
$purposesFull=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$purposesFromDB='a,b,d';
$purposesFromDBArray=explode(',',$purposesFromDB);
foreach($purposesFull as $item){
    $checked = in_array($item,$purposesFromDBArray) ? ' checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="purs[]"'.$checked.'>'.$item;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Your code has the correct output. i will try it first, based on my database.

Comment: Thank you very much. you really got the correct answer. You picture out what the kind of output i want to display. without showing my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this, then:

```
$checkedPurposes = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $purposeColumnFromDatabase);
// then for each checkbox
if (in_array($purposeName, $checkedPurposes)) {
    // echo checked
}
```

The regex ensures that typos regarding the number of spaces around the commas don't matter.

As other users have said in the comments though, this is bad database design. If you can change the schema to move the purposes into their own table, you probably should.